# Harry Potter and Percy Jackson fanfic where Sally Jackson is James Potter's sister

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, percy-jackson

Sally Jackson is James Potter's sister. Sally is friends with Severus. Sally doesn't want anything to do with the war and hides besides some type of magic or wards, but Dumbledore finds out how to go through them only to get Percy on their side.

Sally and Percy want to keep it a secret from Harry that they are family. Percy is the physical education teacher at Hogwarts. Percy takes the curse Katie got from the necklace with skin contact. I think it was set after the Giant War.

The golden trio is suspicious of Percy. And I think that Percy and Severus have an almost brotherly relationship.

Comment: _"but Dumbledore finds out his to go through them"_ This didn't quite make sense so I changed the his to how but my assumption might be wrong. If that isn't what you meant feel free to [edit] it to word it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are thinking of ["The Phoenix of Olympus"](https://www.wattpad.com/story/32871168-phoenix-of-olympus-pjo-harry-potter-unedited-pj)?

> It is three months after Gaea's defeat and Camp Halfblood is hanging by a thread. Percy is a shadow of who he was; a war hardened warrior. He takes on quest after quest to distract him from his losses, but he is still broken, no matter how much he tries to stay strong for the Camp. During a sudden visit to his mom's house, he gets a glimpse of her past while being pulled into another war. His PTSD is at an all time high and he was finally starting to accept their deaths when he discovers the woman he calls mom has her own skeletons hiding in the closet. And they are only now beginning to crawl out from the cracks.
>
> Albus Dumbledore and the Order of the Phoenix are running out of options. Voldemort is getting stronger while their numbers are dwindling. In a desperate attempt to gain allies, he tracks down an old student of his. Sally Jackson, or, as she was known, Sally Potter. Joined by some of her old classmates and friends, he tries to persuade her to join their war effort. To their surprise and disappointment, she adamantly declines only for the reunion to be interrupted by her teenage son. One who possess magic, the one they never knew existed. The Halfblood Wizard: Perseus Jackson.

Comment: Could you [edit] this to explain how it matches the OP’s description?